Pixi.js nested masks(object masked with another masked object) not working
I'm using pixi v7.3.3 and trying to mask a Graphics object with another masked Graphics object, but it doesn't get rendered and no error messages are issued.
I create a pixi Graphics object, mask it with another Graphics object, add them both into a Container, add it to the stage and use it to mask yet another Graphics object. As far as I understand, this should result in the last object being masked, but instead none of them gets rendered. If I disable the masking, it shows that all objects are on the stage.
The code goes something like this(I also have a pixiplayground with it: https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/2ipECggOxAmmvU8o6emmA)
    //create a triangle shape to mask the rectangle
    const mask2 = new PIXI.Graphics();
    mask2.beginFill(0x00ff00);
    mask2.drawPolygon([{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 100, y: 0 }, { x: 50, y: 100 }]);
    mask2.endFill();

    //mask container to hold mask2 and the rectangle it masks
    const maskWrapper = new PIXI.Container();
    maskWrapper.addChild(mask2); //add triangle to container

    //create the rectangle
    const mask = new PIXI.Graphics();
    mask.beginFill(0xff0000);
    mask.drawRect(20, 0, 160, 50);
    mask.endFill();
    mask.mask = mask2; //apply the mask
    maskWrapper.addChild(mask); //add rectangle to container
    app.stage.addChild(maskWrapper);

    //create a rounded rectangle and mask it with maskWrapper
    const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
    graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff);
    graphics.drawRoundedRect(50, 0, 200, 100, 50);
    graphics.endFill();
    graphics.mask = maskWrapper; //apply the mask
    app.stage.addChild(graphics); //add to stage


So my main question is: am I doing it wrong or is this feature just not implemented.
